# password_verify( ) function returns an empty var

Tags: php, password-encryption, password-hash

my password_verify function doesn't return anything and yet i think my code is OK,i tried removing the character escapes but still same results,please help
this is my code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include_once 'db.php';

$uname = stripcslashes($_POST['username']);
$pass = stripcslashes($_POST['userpassword']);
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userpassword']);


 //check if input characters are valid
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/",$uname) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA- Z0-9]*$/",$pass)) {
 header("Location: ../index.php?signin=invalidwords");
 exit();
 }else {    
 //validate username n pwd
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM loginAcc WHERE position='$uname'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $hashedpwd = $row['userpassword'];

 $pw = password_verify($pass,$hashedpwd);
 echo $pass."<br />";
 echo $hashedpwd."<br />";
 echo $pw;
 }
 }else{
 header("Location: ../login.php");
 exit();
 }
```

Comment: i have edited it

Comment: Why do you escape your password when you do not send it to the database? Are you sure that this does not break special chars?

Comment: And **how exactly** did you check that `password_verify` returned something? According to the documentation, there is no case that this method returns "nothing"

Comment: i just edited that so as i can see the results but at the end of the day it gets sent to a database...i also tried removing the escape because in a related post some one had suggested that but still i don't get any results

Comment: maybe you should just run that code and prove that it returns nothing...i really wouldn't waste your time by posting it if it were running

Comment: i would have sent you a screenshot of the display on the browser but i don't have enough badges to post a pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password_verify()` return bool value, and in case your $pw is false, then `echo $pw` will print nothing.

Try to test 2 cases with correct and incorrect password.

Comment: i have tried with both a correct and wrong answer and they both return nothing